# select2 is working in mozilla but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using select2 jQuery in form to display dropdown menu. Everything is working fine but the scrollbar is not displaying in IE. The overflow options are hidden.

```
<tr>
   <td colspan=2>
      <select data-placeholder=" " name="select1" id="select1" style="width:300px;" class = "chosen-select">        
     <option value=""></option>
          <%
        for (String nature :natureList){
             %>
        <option value="<%=nature%>"><%=nature%></option>
        <%
            }

        %></select>
        <br></br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please, provide more information(CSS, jsfiddle and etc)

Comment: i am using select 2.4.0 and added these two files select2.full.js and select2.css. i will try to put in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing out the closing of the `option` in the loop:

```
<select data-placeholder=" " name="select1" id="select1" style="width:300px;" class = "chosen-select">      
     <option value=""></option>
     <% for (String nature :natureList){ %>
        <option value="<%=nature%>"><%=nature%></option><!--<<< this closing tag-->
     <% } %>
</select>
```

Comment: after adding also the same problem occurs

Comment: @Muniappan the snippet you posted i saw this error in the markup, so for better understandings if you could add more information at your question that would be much helpful because _after adding also the same problem occurs_ this comment is not helping.